# Flutter Listview scroll snaps back to top when mouse/finger released

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView within a FutureBuilder and Wrap widget, the ListView has n number of items to show. Everything is brought back from my API and shown correctly, however when scrolling down and letting go of my mouse/finger the ListView will snap back up to the top of the list, however I would like it to hold its place.

I haven't really come across anything online that addresses this and as far as I can tell I am doing this in a standard way.

**Update**
Here is my entire widget, I commented out the `listview` I'm using and added a basic `listview` just counting to 200 items. The problem persists.

```
// ... Imports ...

class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  http.Client client = http.Client();
  String _eventStatusDisplay = "accepted";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: user.fetchUserEvents(client, dotenv.env['BASE_API_URL']!, user.uid),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Wrap(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("See Accepted");
                        setState(() {
                          _eventStatusDisplay = "accepted";
                        });
                      },
                      style: _eventStatusDisplay == "accepted"
                          ? TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground, foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background)
                          : TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background, foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
                      child: const Text("Accepted"),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("See Pending");
                        setState(() {
                          _eventStatusDisplay = "pending";
                        });
                      },
                      style: _eventStatusDisplay == "pending"
                          ? TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground, foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background)
                          : TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background, foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
                      child: const Text("Pending"),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("See Passed");
                        setState(() {
                          _eventStatusDisplay = "declined";
                        });
                      },
                      style: _eventStatusDisplay == "declined"
                          ? TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground, foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background)
                          : TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background, foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
                      child: const Text("Declined"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 200,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text(index.toString());
                  },
                ),
                // ListView.builder(
                //   shrinkWrap: true,
                //   itemCount: user.events[_eventStatusDisplay]?.length,
                //   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                //     return GestureDetector(
                //       onTap: () {
                //         Navigator.pushNamed(context, SingleEventScreen.routeName, arguments: user.events[_eventStatusDisplay]![index]);
                //       },
                //       child: Card(
                //         elevation: 0,
                //         color: Colors.white,
                //         margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                //         child: Row(
                //           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                //           children: [
                //             CircleAvatar(
                //               radius: 30,
                //               child: ClipOval(
                //                 child: FutureBuilder(
                //                   future: user.events[_eventStatusDisplay]?[index].prepareEventPhotoURL(client),
                //                   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                //                     switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                //                       case ConnectionState.none:
                //                       case ConnectionState.waiting:
                //                         return const Icon(Icons.photo);
                //                       default:
                //                         if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
                //                           return const Icon(Icons.photo);
                //                         }

                //                         return CachedNetworkImage(
                //                           fit: BoxFit.cover,
                //                           width: 80,
                //                           height: 80,
                //                           imageUrl: snapshot.data.toString(),
                //                           errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.photo),
                //                           placeholder: (context, url) => const Icon(Icons.photo),
                //                         );
                //                     }
                //                   },
                //                 ),
                //               ),
                //             ),
                //             Expanded(
                //               child: Container(
                //                 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10, right: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
                //                 child: Column(
                //                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                //                   children: [
                //                     Text(
                //                       user.events[_eventStatusDisplay]![index].event.title!,
                //                       maxLines: 1,
                //                       softWrap: false,
                //                       overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                //                       style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                //                     ),
                //                     Text(
                //                       user.events[_eventStatusDisplay]![index].event.description!,
                //                       maxLines: 2,
                //                       softWrap: false,
                //                       overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                //                       style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                //                     ),
                //                   ],
                //                 ),
                //               ),
                //             ),
                //           ],
                //         ),
                //       ),
                //     );
                //   },
                // ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
      floatingActionButton: const NewEventButton(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this issue happen without future? Can you simplify the widget with dummy data that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Still happens

Comment: Can you provide a sample widget ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh You mean without the futurebuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works (Will post another question asking about it) but switching `Wrap` for `Expanded` fixed it